# If you did not get called for an interview, is it safe to assume that your Ph.D. application was not shortlisted? (Please see additional details.)

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, application, interview

Last year, I submitted an application to a PhD program at a Canadian university. The university's website says that shortlisted applicants must expect to be interviewed in February 2022. If I don't get called for an interview this month, can I safely assume that my application is not shortlisted and thus rejected?

Comment: Wait for a reply from them. Assumptions aren't productive. You can also ask for a status update.

Comment: What would you do with the information if in fact you've been rejected, and how would that be different than if you were unsure? Do you have other offer(s) for which you are waiting to respond until you hear back from this university?

Answer (score 2):

Note that it is helpful and efficient for a university to definitely tell people that they've been rejected to avoid follow-on correspondence. The "shortlist" can mean a lot of things and may be a bit volatile. Likewise the "expectation" about February can be a bit "loose".

The most likely thing, if you haven't heard, is that they are busy filling slots and working down the list in some preferred order. Not everyone interviewed will be accepted and some of those who are will drop out, opening a potential slot for someone else. It is impossible to make accurate predictions without hard evidence.

February isn't over yet, of course, this being only the 16th, so even more reason for a bit of patience. But you can ask for an update if you like, and should do so if other deadlines are imminent. But, if it is just to  reassure yourself without a definite reason, I'd suggest patience.